# Does always the sign of $\langle\nabla f (x), v\rangle$ same as the sign of $\langle x, v\rangle$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \Bbb R^d \to R^+$. Does always the sign of $\langle\nabla f (x), v\rangle$ same as the sign of $\langle x, v\rangle$ ?

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Sorry, missed the $+$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $f(x,y)=x^2+1$. Then $\nabla f(x,y)=(2x,0)$. We have that $\langle \nabla f(1,1), (1,-2) \rangle=\langle (2,0), (1,-2) \rangle=2$, whereas $\langle (1,1),(1,-2) \rangle=1-2=-1$.